# Capistrano bundle install gem from git rails not finding gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, bundler

Forked wicked_pdf and added to Gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '= 0.7.2', :git => 'git://github.com/geoffcorey/wicked_pdf.git'
```

Capistrano deploy does

```
bundle install --path vendor/gems --without development
```

All gems show up in `vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems` except wicked_pdf which the repo is cloned to `vendor/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems`.

`bundle list` will show the `wicked_pdf (0.7.2 156782e)` but when I fire up the application via Apache/Passenger, Rails 3.1.3 cannot find wicked_pdf.

Is there something else I should be doing as part of the deploy to have the wicked_pdf build the gem and install as a separate task?

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same problem here (but hosting on heroku).
http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html
"In Bundler 1.0, the bundle package command only packages .gem files, not gems specified using the :git or :path options. This will likely change in the future."

Have a look at:
[Bundler: `bundle package` with a :git source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547502/bundler-bundle-package-with-a-git-source)

and maybe use:
http://underpantsgnome.com/2011/01/05/how-to-install-private-gems-on-heroku
to install the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that (a) you're locking it to an exact version "=0.7.2", but you don't specify a commit ID on the git repo. These two things are in conflict. It's possible that the version entry in the gemspec is no longer 0.7.2 at the tip of the branch you're pulling from git.

If you specify a git location for a gem, it's best not to specify a version, but instead the commit ID you want, i.e.:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', :git => 'git://github.com/geoffcorey/wicked_pdf.git', :ref => 'commit_id_on_github_you_want'
```